# Кто нибудь пробовал создавать базу данных на битриксе с нуля на сайт

Tags: база-данных, битрикс

Удалился сайт с сервера, но мы нашли файлы сайта без база данных. Если вы сталкивались с такой проблемой , можете поделится? Сайт был создан на 1С Битрикс.
Спасибо заранее

Comment: Нет смысла восстанавливать пустую БД. Вам нужна резервная копия. Но прикрутить чистую БД можно изменив параметры в db_conn.php

Answer (score 2):

Битрикс, является cms ориентированной на базу данных. Т.е. база данных необходима для работы любого компонента/модуля. Кроме того битрикс хранит большинство важных настроек в базе данных (настройки сайта, настройки модулей, данные пользователей)

Битрикс обладает функционалом регулярного резервного копирования. К сожалению настройки этого функционала так жде хранятся в базе.

Что можно сделать:

1. Все же поискать бекапы. по умолчанию битрикс складывает файлы резервных копий в папку относительно корня проекта `bitrix\backup`
2. Кроме того битрикс умеет складывать бекап в облако. Запросите техподдержку битрикса проверить наличие бекапов.
3. Проверить настройки хостинга (возможно сам хостинг делает резервные копии)
4. Проверить нет ли в корне сайта файлов с разрешением .sql
5. Можно попытаться восстановить базу данных в ручную, устанавливая все модули в ручную. Но это представляется мало возможным.

Comment: бекап не нашел , проверил на хостинге только папки сайта были , без база данных. Обратились к техподдержку хостинга они сказали , что не существует база данных этого сайта.
Проверил папки сайта ,как  вы написали , там есть файлы .sql

Comment: Дальше что делать?
Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Кладем в корень проекта скрипт восстановления бекапа и запуцскаем его в браузере (если это именно бекап созданный через битрикс) 
Сам скрипт восстановления можно скачать тут: http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/scripts/restore.php

Comment: Если это не битриксовый бекап. (скрипт отработает не верно) стоит попробовать восстановить данные вручную. что то вроде `mysql -u username -ppassword databasename < file.sql`

Comment: восстановить данные вручную , это с нуля добавить в базу данных , через mysql?

Comment: @MR.Aki да. Синтаксис команды привел выше

Comment: Я об этом "mysql -u username -ppassword databasename < file.sql" , как это сделать? можете подробнее обяснить?

Comment: У хостера, как правило, есть панель управления PhpMyAdmin для манипуляций со структурой базы данных. Вот там эти файлы и импортируйте, вряд ли у вас хостинг с доступом по SSH и mysqldump / mysql